# Downloading MIME using GRAPH API REST request is slow compared to MIME file download from outlook web (OWA)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

In our project we started to use GRAPH API v.1.0 introduced some time ago and we wanted our users to be able to download *.eml file. For that we found that this is called MIME stream on MS side.

Long story short:

we use TypeScript (TS) and Graph Client library (@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@^2.2.1);

We use request

await graphClient.api(`/me/messages/${msgID}/$value`).getStream()
The problem we started to notice is that 15MB email (with some attachments of 3-5MB) takes approximately 30sec to download whereas if email is downloaded via Outlook OWA (trhee dots on email > download) it takes few seconds.

Is there a way to increase the download speed using GRAPH api?

I tried to download MIME from graph and expected it to be as fast as downloading MIME from outlook web but it takes twice (maybe more) amount of time to download

EDITED:
As an example: downloading eml (13Mb) from https://outlook.live.com/mail
by uri like: https://attachment.outlook.live.net/owa/outlook_HEXNUM@outlook.com/service.svc/s/DownloadMessage?id=BASE64%3D&token=HUGETOKEN takes 2.5s
downloading eml using GraphApi by uri like:
client.api('/me/messages/${encodeURIComponent(this._fixId(mailId))}/$value').getStream() and reading stream takes 20-30s.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(await GraphAuthDelegado());
IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage graphRequest = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders[
    folder
  ].Messages
  .Request()      
  .Filter($"receivedDateTime ge {today}")
  .Expand(c => new {
    c.Attachments
  })
  .Top(200)
  // .Select(c => new { c.From })
  .GetAsync();
```

folder var is = "Inbox", "JunkEmail", etc. (or search By Id if you wants)
Then you need extract de "ContentBytes" from Attachments.

good code.

Comment: Original question is how to download mime/eml file using graph REST api in typescript